# Is there a record checker for tinydns

Tags: linux, tinydns

I've got a large number of zone-files in tinydns format, and I'm wondering if there is any lint-like tool to test such a zone-file for correctness?

I could write one in perl, testing the format of each line "+", "@", "6", etc.  But it seems like something should be in existence.

Any pointers welcome.

**Update**: I've knocked up a simple script sufficient for my needs:

- http://tinydns-lint.repository.steve.org.uk/file

Answer (score 1):

I once did some checks - I think I used a perl program for that. Not sure if it was [dnswalk](http://www.softpanorama.org/DNS/Tools/dns_audit_tools.shtml). For most of these tools it does not matter what type of DNS-server you have. They do try a zone-transfer and then analyse the results.

**Update** 2012-01-19: I did search my mail-archives today.

The tool I used 6 years ago (and today again) is called "[The DNS-sleuth](http://atrey.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~mj/sleuth/)". It was/is indeed perl-based.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to check the records __before__ I upload them.  So anything relying upon a zone-transfer is too late..

Comment: If you version control on a local system, then you can run a copy of tinyDNS strictly for validation of changes before check-in.  Run the the public DNS on files checked out of the repository.